# How to set callback function in loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Here I want to create cgpa calculation. I take 5 callback function. I want to make this code more shorter.
How can I provide all callback function in a loop?

```js
function cgpa(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5) {
    var s1 = r1 / 100;
    var s2 = r2 / 100;
    var s3 = r3 / 100;
    var s4 = r4 / 100;
    var s5 = r5 / 100;
    var result = s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5
    return result.toFixed(2);
}
function f(point, per) {
    return point * per;
}
var print = cgpa(f(3.68, 5), f(3.33, 10), f(3.33, 25), f(3.45, 15), f(3.58, 10))
console.log(print)
```

Comment: Those aren't really callback functions are they?  You are resolving them and just passing in the value. `cgpa` just takes five values as arguments, not functions

Comment: You received two answers so far. Did you try? Any feedback? Can you mark an answer as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

You could define some functions to sum a series, and multiply a series.

Isolate the data from the algorithm, to avoid hardcoding arguments passed to `f`. It is nicer to have one input data set, and only then start applying functions on that input.

I would also keep `.toFixed` outside your functions, as it has to do with representation. So that should be done where you print.

Then your logic comes down to:

```js
const multiply = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1);
const sum = arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

const data = [[3.68, 5], [3.33, 10], [3.33, 25], [3.45, 15], [3.58, 10]];
const result = sum(data.map(multiply)) / 100;
console.log(result.toFixed(2));
```

I renamed `f` to `multiply` and made it to take an array of arbitrary length. It is now used as a callback function for `.map()`.

Answer (score 0):

Rest parameters to collect all arguments into an array will help.

```js
const cgpa = (...rs) => (rs.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / 100).toFixed(2);
function f(point, per) {
    return point * per;
}
var print = cgpa(f(3.68, 5), f(3.33, 10), f(3.33, 25), f(3.45, 15), f(3.58, 10))
console.log(print)
```